# SaltStack: How to work around "file.recurse doesn't preserve permissions"?

Tags: chmod, saltstack

How to work around [Recursive directory management doesn't preserve permissions](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/2707)?

I want to copy all files in (local) `/monitoring/files/etc` to `/etc` on the minion.

```
copy_files_in_etc:
  file.recurse:
    - source:
      - salt://monitoring/files/etc
    - name: /etc
    - template: jinja
```

Above snippets works, but I am missing the executable bit for some files.

For example scripts in /etc/cron.daily should be executable.

What is the most simple way to work around this?

I search a way to make all files matching this expression to be executable:

```
/etc/cron.(daily|hourly|monthly|weekly/)
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like this was fixed.

```
copy_files_in_etc:
  file.recurse:
    - source:
    - salt://monitoring/files/etc
    - name: /etc
    - template: jinja
    - file_mode: keep
```

Search for `file_mode` at the following link:  https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.recurse

This will cause the files to have the same mode as on the salt master.

Comment: file_mode: keep for `file.recurse`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `file_mode` and `dir_mode`. In your case, `file_mode` should be enough.

```
copy_files_in_etc:
  file.recurse:
    - source:
      - salt://monitoring/files/etc
    - name: /etc
    - template: jinja
    - file_mode: '0755'
```

Comment: Yes, this would set the executable bit for all files in `/etc/cron.(daily|hourly|monthly|weekly/)`, but it would set it on all other files in `/etc`, too.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to make different `id`s (sections) in one SLS file, which each manages a subsection. Having one SLS for the entire `/etc` will also make it hard to roll out changes in a controlled manner. Your `monitoring.sls` could have the `id` `cron_files`, `nagios_files`, `misc_daemon_files`, etc.